# Avalonia GUI application stack debugging

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I've developed an Avalonia GUI application, and I'm encountering an issue where, occasionally, after switching windows, it becomes unresponsive, and I'm unable to click on any buttons. Despite checking my logs, I couldn't find any information that would help me diagnose the problem.

I'm currently running the application in debugging mode. Can someone guide me on how to debug this issue effectively? Additionally, I'm interested in extracting all logs, not just the ones I write.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have all CLR exception breakpoints enabled? There is a setting, at least in Visual Studio, and Rider, for this, and it might help you find out why things are locking up.